# MenuIcon not found in material-ui/icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a basic navigation bar with Material UI. The boilerplate template on Material-UI's doc site https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/ is returning the following error in the browser:
"Attempted import error: '@material-ui/icons' does not contain a default export (imported as 'MenuIcon')."
I have installed @material-ui/core and @material-ui/icons using npm. See package.json:

```
{
  "name": "profile_v4",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

My Navbar.js component file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons";

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

I have looked elsewhere on SO for a solve but all answers are a variation on "You have not installed npm material-ui/icons package" so I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Use a named import, i.e. `import { MenuIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";` or fully qualify the default import, i.e. `import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MenuIcon";` See [icons usage](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#usage).

Comment: Neither of these solutions solve the problem. Both have been tried. Not a typo. Thanks.

Comment: If you search the icons [here](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/) it appears it should be `import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';`. Official docs are often helpful. It's still a typo IMO, but Mark has the correct imports in their answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is with how you are importing the icon. You can fix it by either changing to a named import or provide the full path to the icon.

```js
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { Menu as MenuIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

Comment: Adding "/Menu" to the path worked. I wish this was more clearly explained in the Material-UI docs. Thanks Mark

Comment: It's documented in the [usage section](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#usage) of the Material UI docs.  Kind of have to hunt for documentation since Material UI is pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

In v5.10.10 this component is not installed with mui

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Run an install for the icons-material will bring them into your node_modules/@mui folder.

You can repeat this process for other missing components you are trying to use.

Comment: It seems it may be excluded from the core package because of its size... (133 MB)